# CSS not applying properly after jQuery manipulation?

Tags: jquery, css

I have an image that swaps out for a smaller image when you click it, like a button being depressed, via this rule:

```
div#about.mouseDown {
    background: transparent url("../resources/about_down.png") no-repeat top left;
}
```

To keep it from staying that way if someone clicks and moves the mouse out of the div, I have this:

```
$("#about").mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).css("background", 'transparent url("/resources/about.png") no-repeat top left');
        });
```

However, once that is called (once you move your mouse into and then out of the div in question) the CSS rule above ceases to apply. I checked in the inspector, and it's simply no longer being applied.

Why could that be?

Comment: Maybe you actually want to toggle the styles?

Comment: @j08691, that's valid CSS. It matches a `<div>` element whose `id` is `about` and which exposes the `mouseDown` class.

Comment: @j08691 The first code block is of course valid css... ;) he selects an DOM-`Node` with an `ID` and a `class`

Comment: Of course. I didn't look at it as a class.

Comment: Can you prepare a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net) please?

Comment: You don't need one! You understand the problem completely! You've already made me understand what's wrong. I have to find a solution. :)

Comment: @Aerovistae Great! I'm delighted :) Now, mark the question as answered, if it is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that jQuery adds the style via **inline**-code so your div becomes something like this:

```
<div id="about" class="mouseDown" style="background: transparent url('../resources/about_down.png') no-repeat top left;"></div>
```

To make your css work again, you've to use `!important` (what I can't recommend):

```
div#about.mouseDown {
    background: transparent url("../resources/about_down.png") no-repeat top left !important;
}
```

or to put the css into a js-function too:

```
$("#about").mousedown(function(){
    this.style.background = "transparent url('/resources/about_down.png') no-repeat top left";
});
```

**Update**

Another good point: [CSS not applying properly after jQuery manipulation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324439/css-not-applying-properly-after-jquery-manipulation/17324557?noredirect=1#comment25129884_17324557)

Comment: or you could just involve `$('#about').removeAttr('style');` at the opportune moment to get rid of the inline style altogether.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea That's never a good idea, since we don't know if he adds more styling via jQuery ;)

Comment: assuming he does vs assuming he doesn't ... i doubt assuming either way is a good way to go. i was just providing the information. and btw, `!important` is never a good idea either, as its avoidable 99.999% of the time.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea Yeah, I've to agree :) Note: *what I can't recommend*

Comment: I'd recommend using `addClass()` in the `mouseDown` event, then a `removeClass()` on both the `mouseUp` and `mouseLeave` events. Then it can be neatly handled by CSS.

Comment: @Phylogenesis Great idea, I'll link to your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
$("#about").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).css("backgroundUrl", "url('/resources/about.png')");
}).mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).css("backgroundUrl", "url('../resources/about_down.png')");
});
```

Comment: Sorry, no! That would make the button appear clicked every time your mouse moved past it, regardless of whether you clicked it!